# Why does julia not recognize the type of an array that is passed as a function argument, listing it as Any instead?

Tags: arrays, julia

I am defining a function in julia that accepts a  vector (specifically `Vector{Complex128}`). When I look at the output of `@code_warntype` I see that the variable type is listed as `Any`. This can potentially have speed implications, as I understand. Here is a simple version of the code, for example:

```
function abc(h::Vector{Complex128})
   a=1+2
end
```

The output from `@code_warntype` is

```
julia> @code_warntype abc(zeros(Complex128,2))
Variables:
  #self#::#abc
  h::Any
  a::Int64

Body:
  begin 
    SSAValue(0) = (Base.add_int)(1, 2)::Int64
    return SSAValue(0)
  end::Int64
```

The type of the variable `h` is listed as `Any`. I am new to julia and don't really know if I am missing something here. This behaviour doesn't seem specific to `Vector{Complex128}`, I get the same behaviour with `Vector{Float64}` as well. Am I annotating the variable type incorrectly here, or is this how it is supposed to work? I'm using julia v0.6.0, if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the compiler has optimized it away so it doesn't even exist. The way it's printed has changed in v0.6.1 to be more clear:

```
julia> function abc(h::Vector{Complex128})
          a=1+2
       end
abc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype abc(zeros(Complex128,2))
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  h <optimized out>
  a <optimized out>

Body:
  begin
      SSAValue(0) = (Base.add_int)(1, 2)::Int64
      return SSAValue(0)
  end::Int64
```