# Julia function type instability

Tags: julia

Still a bit confused about to to make functions type stable in Julia.
Here is my function

```
function tran7(C::Array{Float64,1}, flux_up::Float64, D::Array{Float64,1},
    v::Array{Float64,1}, AFDW::Array{Float64,1}, VF::Array{Float64,1},
    VF_mid::Array{Float64,1})

    C_up = Float64[];
    flux = Array{Float64,1}(N+1); dC = Array{Float64, 1}(N)

    C_up = (flux_up + VF[1]*(D[1]/dx_aux[1] + (1-AFDW[1])*v[1])*C[1])/
    (VF[1]*(D[1]/dx_aux[1] + AFDW[1]*v[1]))

    flux = -VF.*D.*(vcat(C_up,C,C[N])[2:(N+2)] -
            vcat(C_up,C,C[N])[1:(N+1)])./dx_aux +
            VF.*v.*(AFDW.*vcat(C_up,C) + (1-AFDW).*vcat(C,C[N]))
    flux[1] = flux_up
    dC = -(flux[2:(N+1)] - flux[1:N])./(VF_mid.*dx)
    return dC
end
```

And here is the @code_warntype results

```
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  C::Array{Float64,1}
  flux_up::Float64
  D::Array{Float64,1}
  v::Array{Float64,1}
  AFDW::Array{Float64,1}
  VF::Array{Float64,1}
  VF_mid::Array{Float64,1}
  #200::##200#203
  #201::##201#204
  #202::##202#205
  C_down <optimized out>
  C_up::ANY
  flux::ANY
  dC::ANY
  #temp#@_16::Core.MethodInstance
  #temp#@_17::ANY
  #temp#@_18::Core.MethodInstance
  #temp#@_19::ANY
  #temp#@_20 <optimized out>

Body:
  begin 
      C_up::ANY = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), 
Array{Float64,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{Float64,1}, 0, 0, 0)) # line 5:
      $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Float64,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{Float64,1}, 0, 0, 0)) # line 6:
  flux::ANY = (Array{Float64,1})((Main.N + 1)::ANY)::Array{Float64,1} # line 6:
  dC::ANY = (Array{Float64,1})(Main.N)::Array{Float64,1} # line 8:
  SSAValue(21) = (Base.arrayref)(VF::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64
  SSAValue(20) = (((Base.arrayref)(D::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64 / (Main.getindex)(Main.dx_aux, 1)::ANY)::ANY + (Base.mul_float)((Base.sub_float)((Base.sitofp)(Float64, 1)::Float64, (Base.arrayref)(AFDW::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64)::Float64, (Base.arrayref)(v::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64)::Float64)::ANY
  SSAValue(19) = (Base.arrayref)(C::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64
  $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
  # meta: location operators.jl * 424
  SSAValue(22) = ((SSAValue(21) * SSAValue(20))::ANY * SSAValue(19))::ANY
  # meta: pop location
  $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
  C_up::ANY = ((flux_up::Float64 + SSAValue(22))::ANY / ((Base.arrayref)(VF::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64 * (((Base.arrayref)(D::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64 / (Main.getindex)(Main.dx_aux, 1)::ANY)::ANY + (Base.mul_float)((Base.arrayref)(AFDW::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64, (Base.arrayref)(v::Array{Float64,1}, 1)::Float64)::Float64)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY # line 11:
  #200::##200#203 = $(Expr(:new, :(Main.##200#203)))
  SSAValue(1) = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for -(::Array{Float64,1}), :(Main.-), :(VF)))
  SSAValue(3) = (Main.vcat)(C_up::ANY, C::Array{Float64,1}, (Main.getindex)(C::Array{Float64,1}, Main.N)::ANY)::ANY
  SSAValue(4) = (Main.getindex)(SSAValue(3), (Main.colon)(2, (Main.N + 2)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY
  SSAValue(5) = (Main.vcat)(C_up::ANY, C::Array{Float64,1}, (Main.getindex)(C::Array{Float64,1}, Main.N)::ANY)::ANY
  SSAValue(6) = (Main.getindex)(SSAValue(5), (Main.colon)(1, (Main.N + 1)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY
  SSAValue(7) = (SSAValue(4) - SSAValue(6))::ANY
  SSAValue(33) = D::Array{Float64,1}
  SSAValue(34) = Main.dx_aux
  $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
  # meta: location broadcast.jl broadcast 434
  SSAValue(26) = SSAValue(7)
  SSAValue(27) = SSAValue(34)
  # meta: location broadcast.jl containertype 34
  SSAValue(25) = (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)(Array, (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)((Base.Broadcast._containertype)((Base.Broadcast.typeof)(SSAValue(26))::DataType)::ANY, (Base.Broadcast._containertype)((Base.Broadcast.typeof)(SSAValue(27))::DataType)::ANY)::ANY)::UNION{TYPE{ARRAY}, TYPE{BASE.SPARSEARRAYS.HIGHERORDERFNS.PROMOTETOSPARSE}}
  unless (SSAValue(25) isa Type{Array})::Bool goto 37
  #temp#@_16::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for promote_containertype(::Type{Array}, ::Type{Array})
  goto 46
  37: 
  unless (SSAValue(25) isa Type{Base.SparseArrays.HigherOrderFns.PromoteToSparse})::Bool goto 41
  #temp#@_16::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for promote_containertype(::Type{Array}, ::Type{Base.SparseArrays.HigherOrderFns.PromoteToSparse})
  goto 46
  41: 
  goto 43
  43: 
  #temp#@_17::ANY = (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)(Array, SSAValue(25))::UNION{TYPE{ARRAY}, TYPE{BASE.SPARSEARRAYS.HIGHERORDERFNS.PROMOTETOSPARSE}}
  goto 48
  46: 
  #temp#@_17::ANY = $(Expr(:invoke, :(#temp#@_16), :(Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype), Array, SSAValue(25)))
  48: 
  # meta: pop location
  # meta: pop location
  $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
  SSAValue(8) = (Base.Broadcast.broadcast_c)(#200::##200#203, #temp#@_17::ANY, SSAValue(1), SSAValue(33), SSAValue(7), SSAValue(34))::ANY
  #201::##201#204 = $(Expr(:new, :(Main.##201#204)))
  SSAValue(12) = ((Base.broadcast)(Main.*, AFDW::Array{Float64,1}, (Main.vcat)(C_up::ANY, C::Array{Float64,1})::ANY)::ANY + (Base.broadcast)(Main.*, $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for -(::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1}), :(Main.-), 1, :(AFDW))), (Main.vcat)(C::Array{Float64,1}, (Main.getindex)(C::Array{Float64,1}, Main.N)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY
  $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
  # meta: location broadcast.jl broadcast 434
  # meta: location broadcast.jl containertype 34
  SSAValue(28) = (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)(Array, (Base.Broadcast._containertype)((Base.Broadcast.typeof)(SSAValue(12))::DataType)::ANY)::UNION{TYPE{ARRAY}, TYPE{BASE.SPARSEARRAYS.HIGHERORDERFNS.PROMOTETOSPARSE}}
  unless (SSAValue(28) isa Type{Array})::Bool goto 62
  #temp#@_18::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for promote_containertype(::Type{Array}, ::Type{Array})
  goto 71
  62: 
  unless (SSAValue(28) isa Type{Base.SparseArrays.HigherOrderFns.PromoteToSparse})::Bool goto 66
  #temp#@_18::Core.MethodInstance = MethodInstance for promote_containertype(::Type{Array}, ::Type{Base.SparseArrays.HigherOrderFns.PromoteToSparse})
  goto 71
  66: 
  goto 68
  68: 
  #temp#@_19::ANY = (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)(Array, SSAValue(28))::UNION{TYPE{ARRAY}, TYPE{BASE.SPARSEARRAYS.HIGHERORDERFNS.PROMOTETOSPARSE}}
  goto 73
  71: 
  #temp#@_19::ANY = $(Expr(:invoke, :(#temp#@_18), :(Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype), Array, SSAValue(28)))
  73: 
  # meta: pop location
  # meta: pop location
  $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
  SSAValue(13) = (Base.Broadcast.broadcast_c)(#201::##201#204, #temp#@_19::ANY, VF::Array{Float64,1}, v::Array{Float64,1}, SSAValue(12))::ANY
  flux::ANY = (SSAValue(8) + SSAValue(13))::ANY # line 14:
  (Main.setindex!)(flux::ANY, flux_up::Float64, 1)::ANY # line 15:
  #202::##202#205 = $(Expr(:new, :(Main.##202#205)))
  SSAValue(15) = -(((Main.getindex)(flux::ANY, (Main.colon)(2, (Main.N + 1)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY - (Main.getindex)(flux::ANY, (Main.colon)(1, Main.N)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY
  SSAValue(35) = VF_mid::Array{Float64,1}
  SSAValue(36) = Main.dx
  $(Expr(:inbounds, false))
  # meta: location broadcast.jl broadcast 434
  SSAValue(32) = (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)((Base.Broadcast._containertype)((Base.Broadcast.typeof)(SSAValue(15))::DataType)::ANY, (Base.Broadcast.promote_containertype)(Array, (Base.Broadcast._containertype)((Base.Broadcast.typeof)(SSAValue(36))::DataType)::ANY)::UNION{TYPE{ARRAY}, TYPE{BASE.SPARSEARRAYS.HIGHERORDERFNS.PROMOTETOSPARSE}})::ANY
  # meta: pop location
  $(Expr(:inbounds, :pop))
  dC::ANY = (Base.Broadcast.broadcast_c)(#202::##202#205, SSAValue(32), SSAValue(15), SSAValue(35), SSAValue(36))::ANY # line 16:
  return dC::ANY
  end::ANY
```

I have a few questions. (1) why do the variables that were preallocated (`dC`, `C_up`, `flux`) still have type  `any`? (2) if I have a parameter (constant) defined outside of the function, such as `dx_aux` in here, is there an advantage of including it as an input? (3) what's the best way to deal with complex intermediary computational results?

Comment: Can you post the @code_warntype call as well?

Comment: Where is N defined ?

Comment: N is defined outside the function.

Comment: This is not an MWE, in that we can't run the code as posted and reproduce. You're more likely to get an answer if you provide that.

Comment: I can't find the SO question, but this should be 0.6 issue. Basically your `dC` etc values are optimised out of the function by the compiler - they're never actually allocated, so they show up as any. They would show up as not used or something similar in 0.7. I'll see if I can find the other SO question on this.

Comment: Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201832/why-does-julia-not-recognize-the-type-of-an-array-that-is-passed-as-a-function-a

Comment: Is dx_aux declared with "const"?

Comment: `(Main.getindex)(Main.dx_aux, 1)::ANY)::ANY`
This shows that the type of dx_aux is unknown and so is dx_aux[1].  

Are N, dx and dx_aux global variables ? Did you declare them with const keyword ?

As Michael Borregaard pointed out you should supply a complete MWE to get more help.

Answer (score 3):

`C_up`, `flux`, and `dC` are not defined in the function header, so I assume they are globals. Globals can always change types because

```
x = 3
x = 2.0
```

works in the REPL, so the functions do not specialize on the type of global variables out of fear of getting the type wrong. However, if it's a constant,

```
const x = 3
```

then the compiler can make the assumption it won't change, and thus specialize on the type and fix this issue. Note that the value of arrays is their reference, so

```
const x = [3,4,5]
x[2] = 6
```

is fine because the value of `x` is just the reference, so it doesn't change even when internal values of the array change.

> (3) what's the best way to deal with complex intermediary computational results?

Cache arrays like you have here, or callable types with a cache, or ..., this is far too broad to answer well.

I'll leave with two links:

http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/7-julia-gotchas-handle/

That describes that global variable problem and why it happens. But also:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8870

suggests a new syntax:

```
x::Int = 3
```

so that non-constant globals can have a declared type that is inferred in further functions. This seems like it won't make 1.0, but it will be a 1.x.

Comment: Say if I have a global variable and I pass it as an argument for a function and I declare the type of the global variable there. In this case in my tests it doesn't seem to matter whether I declare this global constant out side the function, or if I move the variable into the function.      `N=1000`  `function myfun(N::Int64) x = N+1 end`

Comment: Julia specializes its compilation of functions on its arguments. Another way to think about this is that Julia's compilation and optimization unit is the function. Anything outside of a function is compiled every time its called and not very optimized. Everything in a function is optimized. Everything passed to a function is optimized on.